# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python. I want this code to run in tkinter. Before i was adding tkinter to code, it worked, but now i get an error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'. I didn't changed that part of code.

I tried `try-except` and `if meta is not None:`, When i try `if meta is not None:
        return parse_data(meta.attrs['content'])`
code runs but tkinter shows an empty label.

```
entry0 = tk.Entry(frame)
entry0.grid(row = 0, column = 1)


URL = "https://www.instagram.com/{}/"

def parse_data(s):
    data ={}
    s = s.split("-")[0]
    s = s.split()
    data['Followers'] = s[0]
    data['Following'] = s[2]
    data['posts'] = s[4]
    return data

def scrape_data(username):
    r = requests.get(URL.format(username))
    s = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    meta = s.find("meta",property="og:description")
    return parse_data(meta.attrs['content'])


if __name__ =="__main__": 
    username = entry0.get()
    data = scrape_data(username)


def func():
    label2 = tk.Label(frame, text = data)
    label2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

I expected code to run properly, but i got an error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'.
I want tkinter to show `data` in `label2` but

Comment: Presumably this is because `meta = s.find("meta",property="og:description")` returns `None`. It probably doesn't find what you are looking for. I don't think that `tkinter` has anything to do with such an error.

Comment: Clearly `meta` is `None`, so `s.find("meta",property="og:description")` is failing.   A `if meta is not None:` test should work, but you don't show how you applied that.

Comment: @cdarke I'm sorry im new to stackoverflow. I tried it like this: `if meta is not None:
        return parse_data(meta.attrs['content'])` code runs but tkinter is just showing a blank label.

Comment: That's what you would expect, since you are returning `None` from the function if you don't have an explicit `return`.  What did you expect tkinter to display?  You should determine why the `s.find()` is failing and handle that.

Comment: @cdarke I expected tkinter to show `data` in label because the code without tkinter worked with `print(data)` and i used `input` instead of `entry.get()`

Comment: Maybe `entry.get()` is not getting the string that you think it gets. Without a [mcve] it is impossible for us to say why code that we don't even see is failing.

Comment: if something doesn't works then you can use `print()` to see values in variables and display information which part of code is executed. Maybe you have different values in variables then you expect or code runs in different order then you expect. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: is it you full code ? and where is `root.mainloop()` ? All GUI frameworks (probably in all languages) works different then normal `input()`. it doesn't wait for your text in `Entry` so code in `if __name__ =="__main__":` can be executed even before you seen window. And it means you may have empty string in `username`. You should use `print(username)` to check it. In GUI it is good to have `Button` to run code because you can be sure that code will be executed after you put text in `Entry`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your full code but I think your problem is that you don't know how GUI frameworks works.

First: `mainloop` starts everything and it shows window. Everything before `mainloop()` is executed before you even see window.

Second: `Entry` doesn't wait for your text and your `entry.get()` may get empty string before you even see tkinter's window.

It is good to have `Button` in window to start your function after you put text in `Entry`.

`Mainloop` shows window and it also checks if you pressed button and it executes function assigned to button. It does many other things - get key/mouse event from system, sends events to widgets, update data in widget, execute function to buttons, redraw widgets and window, etc. It works till you close window.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tkinter as tk

URL = "https://www.instagram.com/{}/"

def parse_data(s):
    data = {}
    s = s.split("-")[0]
    s = s.split()
    data['Followers'] = s[0]
    data['Following'] = s[2]
    data['posts'] = s[4]
    return data

def scrape_data(username):
    r = requests.get(URL.format(username))
    s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    meta = s.find("meta", property="og:description")
    return parse_data(meta.attrs['content'])

def on_click():
    username = entry.get()
    username = username.strip()
    if username:
        data = scrape_data(username)
        label['text'] = data
    else:
        label['text'] = "Need username"
        
if __name__ =="__main__": 

    root = tk.Tk()

    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

    label = tk.Label(root)
    label.grid(row=1, column=1)
    
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Scrape", command=on_click)
    button.grid(row=2, column=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT: 2021.06.01**

This code is 2 years old. Currently `instagram` uses JavaScript to add elements on page but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: I tried your code. It still gives the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'`. Is something need to be edited in your code?

Comment: @EzyGrip this code is 2 years old - web page could change all HTML few times and code may not work now. And modern pages use JavaScript to add elements but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.